# Checkbox : Change root Styles

Tags: css, typescript, checkbox, material-ui, styles

How can I change the root styles in Checkbox. This does not work.

```
 <CheckboxItem
                      onChange={()}
                      checked={isChecked}
                      label="Show Checkbox"
                      classes={{ root: classes.checkbox }}
                    />
```

```
className={{ root: classes.checkbox }}
```

is erroring out as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either using the `sx` property like the documentation suggests:

```
<Checkbox
  {...label}
  defaultChecked
  sx={{
    color: pink[800],
    '&.Mui-checked': {
      color: pink[600],
    },
  }}
/>
```

Another way you can create a styled component:

```
const CheckBoxStyled = styled(Checkbox)`
  root: {
    "&$checked": {
      "& .MuiIconButton-label": {
        color: "red",
        ...
      },
      ...
    }
  },
`;

<CheckBoxStyled checked value="TestValue" onChange={handleChange}/>
```

In case the above it's not a big help can you please provide some more info of what you want to change and the version of MUI and probably can send you a working sample.